# Trajectories, Paths Clustering Using Expectation Maximization

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, machine-learning, clustering

**[tl;dr]: Go to the question and the part below the question directly. The question should be easy. I'm a newbie on probability.**

Trajectories are a series of paths, each of them consisting of multiple positions $(x, y)$.

I am trying to implement this [paper(need paid access)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0278364904048962?journalCode=ijra) which in the first chapter, it discusses how to cluster trajectories data of human walking using Expectation Maximization to determine motion patterns.

The author's explanation of trajectories is

> Accordingly, we assume that the input
> to our algorithm is a collection of trajectories $s = {s_{1},...,s_{i} }$
> between resting places. The output is a number of different
> types of motion patterns $θ = {θ_{1},...,θ_{M} }$ a person might exhibit in their natural environment. Each trajectory $s_{i}$ consists
> of a sequence $s_{i} = \{ s_{1}^{i}, s_{2}^{i}, ...,s_{i}^{i} \}$ Accordingly.

The Expectation Maximization algorithm takes two steps, E-step and M-step. According to the author:

> The optimization involves two steps: calculating the expectations $E[c_{i m} \mid \theta^{[j]}, d] $
> given the current model $θ^{[j]}$, and
> finding the new model $θ^{[j+1]}$ that has the maximum expected
> likelihood under these expectations. The first of these two
> steps are typically referred to as the E-step (short for expectation step), and the latter as the M-step (short for maximization
> step).

The equation for E-step is as follows:

$$
E\left[C_{i m} \mid \theta^{[j]}, d\right]=\eta^{\prime} \prod_{t=1}^{T} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^{2}}\left\|x_{i}^{t}-\mu_{m}^{\lceil t / \beta \rceil [j]}\right\|^{2}\right)
$$

Where

- $d, i$: Trajectories, index of the trajectory.
- $M, m$: Number of different types of motion patterns.
- $C_{i m}$: Binary value 0 or 1. "correspondence variables" defined by the author. It is 1 if the $i$th trajectory corresponds to the $m$th pattern.
- $j$: Model iteration number.
- $\eta^{\prime}$: Normalization constants.
- $T, t$: Trajectory length(number of positions inside a trajectory), index of positions in the trajectory.
- $\sigma$: Gaussian distributions standard deviation.
- $x, x_{i}^{t}$:Position on trajectories. The $t$th position on the $i$th trajectory.
- $\mu$: EM means.
- **$K$: Gaussian distributions??? $K$is not in the formula but is needed to calculate $\beta$.**
- **$\beta$: subsequent positions on the trajectories??? $\beta = \lceil T / K \rceil$???**

**Question: What is the meaning of these two variables exactly? $K$ and $\beta$.**

The only time the author mentioned about $K$:

> We begin with the description of our model of motion patterns, which is subsequently estimated from data using EM.
> A motion pattern denoted as $θ_{m}$ with $1 ≤ m ≤ M$ is represented by $K$ probability distributions $P (x \vert θ_{m}^{k})$ where $M$ is
> the number of different types of motion patterns in which a
> person is engaged.

The only time the author mentioned about $\beta$:

> For each $θ_{m}^{k}$ the probability distribution $P(x | θ_{m}^{k})$ is computed based on $β = \lceil T/K \rceil$ subsequent positions on the trajectories. Accordingly, $P(x | θ_{m}^{k})$ specifies the probability that
> the person is at location $x$ after $[(k − 1) · β + 1; k · β]$ steps
> given that it is engaged in motion pattern m. Thus, we calculate the likelihood of a trajectory $d_{i}$ under the $m$th motion
> pattern $θ_{m}$ as $$P\left(d_{i} \mid \theta_{m}\right)=\prod_{t=1}^{T} P\left(x_{i}^{t} \mid \theta_{m}^{\lceil t / \beta\rceil}\right)$$

I need to implement both the E-step and M-step to do clustering on my trajectory data. Just a reference, here's the equation for M-step:
$$
\mu_{m}^{k[j+1]}=\frac{1}{\beta} \cdot \sum_{t=(k-1) \cdot \beta+1}^{k \cdot \beta} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{I} E\left[C_{i m} \mid \theta^{[j]}, d\right] x_{i}^{t}}{\sum_{i=1}^{I} E\left[C_{i m} \mid \theta^{[j]}, d\right]} .
$$